# Building a Binary Expression Tree in Ada

Tags: tree, expression, binary-tree, ada

I am attempting to build an Expression tree from fully parenthesized infix notation in Ada.  I am building the tree recursively.  Each node has a data field, and a pointer to left and right children.  The following is what I have put together for implementation.

```
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Text_IO;
USE Ada.Text_IO;

PACKAGE BODY Tree_Expression IS
   FUNCTION To_String (
         Input : Tree_String)
     RETURN String IS
      Last : Natural := 0;
   BEGIN
      FOR I IN Input'RANGE LOOP
         IF Input(I) /= ' ' THEN
            Last := Last + 1;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN Input(Input'First .. Last);
   END To_String;

   FUNCTION To_Number (
         Input : String)
     RETURN Float IS
      Output : Integer;
      First  : Integer  := - 1;
      Last   : Positive;
   BEGIN
      FOR I IN Input'RANGE LOOP
         IF Input(I) IN '0'..'9' THEN
            First := I;
            EXIT;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      IF First = -1 THEN
         RAISE Number_Error;
      END IF;
      IF First = Input'First THEN
         Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(
            From => Input,
            Item => Output,
            Last => Last);
         RETURN Float(Output);
      ELSE
         Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(Input(First .. Input'Last), Output, Last);
         RETURN Float(Output);
      END IF;
   END To_Number;

   FUNCTION To_Char (
         Input : String)
     RETURN Character IS
   BEGIN
      FOR I IN Input'RANGE LOOP
         IF Input(I) = '*' OR Input(I) = '/' OR Input(I) = '+' OR Input(I) = '-' OR Input(I) = '^' THEN
            RETURN Input(I);
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
      RAISE Operator_Error;
   END To_Char;

   FUNCTION Construct_ExpressionTree (
         Expression_String : String;
         First,
         Last              : Natural)
     RETURN Expression_Node_Ptr IS
      Depth           : Natural     := 0;
      Pos             : Natural     := 0;
      Operator        : Character   := ' ';
      Number_String   : Tree_String;
      Operator_String : Tree_String;
      Build_Num_Str   : Natural     := Number_String'First;
   BEGIN
      FOR I IN First..Last LOOP
         CASE(Expression_String(I)) IS
            WHEN '(' =>
               Depth := Depth + 1;
            WHEN ')' =>
               Depth := Depth - 1;
            WHEN '+'|'-'|'*'|'/'|'^' =>
               IF Depth = 1 THEN
                  Pos := I;
                  Operator := Expression_String(I);
                  EXIT;
               END IF;
            WHEN OTHERS =>
               NULL;
         END CASE;
      END LOOP;
      IF Operator = '+' OR Operator = '-' OR Operator = '*' OR Operator = '/' OR Operator = '^' THEN
         Operator_String(Operator_String'First) := Operator;
         FOR I IN Operator_String'RANGE LOOP
            IF I > Operator_String'First THEN
               Operator_String(I) := ' ';
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
         RETURN Binary_Expression_Tree.Create_Node(Operator_String, Construct_ExpressionTree(Expression_String, 
            Expression_String'First+1, Pos-1), Construct_ExpressionTree(Expression_String, Pos+1, Expression_String'Last-1));
      ELSE
         FOR I IN First..Last LOOP
            IF Expression_String(I) IN '0'..'9' THEN
               Number_String(Build_Num_Str) := Expression_String(I);
               Build_Num_Str := Build_Num_Str +1;
            ELSIF Expression_String(I) = ')' THEN
               EXIT;
            ELSE
               NULL;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
         IF Build_Num_Str = Number_String'First THEN
            RAISE Number_Error;
         END IF;
         FOR I IN Build_Num_Str..Number_String'Last LOOP
            Number_String(I) := ' ';
         END LOOP;
         RETURN Binary_Expression_Tree.Create_Node(Number_String, NULL, NULL);
      END IF;

   END Construct_ExpressionTree;

   FUNCTION Evaluate_Expression (
         Node : Expression_Node_Ptr)
     RETURN Float IS
      FUNCTION Eval (
            Node : Expression_Node_Ptr)
        RETURN Float IS
         Data     : Tree_String := Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Data (Node);
         Operator : Character;
      BEGIN
         Operator := To_Char(Data);
         CASE Operator IS
            WHEN '+' =>
               RETURN Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Left_Child(Node)) + Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Right_Child(Node));
            WHEN '-' =>
               RETURN Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Left_Child(Node)) - Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Right_Child(Node));
            WHEN '*' =>
               RETURN Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Left_Child(Node)) * Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Right_Child(Node));
            WHEN '/' =>
               RETURN Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Left_Child(Node)) / Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Right_Child(Node));
            WHEN '^' =>
               RETURN Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Left_Child(Node)) ** Natural(Eval(Binary_Expression_Tree.Get_Right_Child(Node)));
            WHEN OTHERS =>
               RAISE Expression_Error;
         END CASE;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN Operator_Error =>
            RETURN To_Number(Data);
      END Eval;
   BEGIN
      RETURN Eval (Node);
   END Evaluate_Expression;

   FUNCTION Infix_Notation (
         Node : Expression_Node_Ptr)
     RETURN String IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN Binary_Expression_Tree.Inorder_Traversal(Node);

   END Infix_Notation;

   FUNCTION Prefix_Notation (
         Node : Expression_Node_Ptr)
     RETURN String IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN Binary_Expression_Tree.Preorder_Traversal(Node);
   END Prefix_Notation;

   FUNCTION Postfix_Notation (
         Node : Expression_Node_Ptr)
     RETURN String IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN Binary_Expression_Tree.Postorder_Traversal(Node);
   END Postfix_Notation;

END Tree_Expression;
```

My issue is that when I enter an expression, for example, ((5+6)*(1-3)), the tree is being built incorrectly.  My output from an in order traversal of the tree built from that expression is 5+6*5+6-3 instead of 5+6*1-3.  Basically, the left child of the root's right child (1) is not being added to the tree, and (5+6) is being added again in its place.

Create_Node, which is a function called in the construction function, looks like:

```
FUNCTION Create_Node (
         Data        : Item_Type;
         Left_Child,
         Right_Child : Node_Ptr)
     RETURN Node_Ptr IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN NEW Node_Type'(Data, Left_Child, Right_Child);
   END Create_Node;
```

This is for homework - I'm just looking for pointers as to what is going wrong in general, and sections of my code that it would make sense to look at.  Thanks in advance.

Edited after feedback:
Here's my thought process, hopefully it tracks:
- Start by finding the operator at depth = 1, which will be the root node for the tree.
- Once I have that, I create a node, with everything to the left being sent back into the construct function as the left child, and everything to the right being sent back in as the right child.  As I understand it, this is the recursive method to building the tree.
- Every time the function is called, it should find the operator at depth 1, which will be the next node down.  If no operators are found, it should make leaf nodes with numbers.  There's a loop there that parses input and builds a number string to store in the node, so multiple digits should work.  I've been thinking about it, and I'm thinking something may be fishy with the First and Last being sent back into Construct_ExpressionTree.

And I was just playing with it and got a test case to work.  I was sending the wrong info back into the function.

Comment: Forgot to mention - the function being used to build the tree is called Construct_ExpressionTree and starts about halfway through the code.

Comment: 1> Ive only had a very quick look, and i am suspicious of how you determine what depth your nodes need to be. 2> This is essentially a recursive problem, is there a reason why you are not using recursion ? 3> you check for 'Depth = 1', does this imply you will only get 2 levels of tree ? 4> you only check for single digit numbers, is this sufficient ?

Answer (score 1):

Although not specific to Ada, you're trying to build an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is "essentially a recursive problem," as noted by @NWS. As you only need productions for `expression`, `term` and `factor`, a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) will construct the tree implicitly. In effect, the call tree *is* the parse tree, as suggested [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2013/lectures/Recursive-descent.pdf). See also the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2419972/230513).

Answer (score 1):

As Trashgod mentioned recursive decent is your answer, I'm sure his links are quite informative (they usually are), but he forgot perhaps one of the most accessible texts on the problem: Jack Crenshaw's [Let's Build a Compiler](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/).

In addition to that, there is the classic book by Niklaus Wirth [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs](http://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/math/Data_Structure_And_Algorithms/Algorithms%20and%20Data%20Structures%20-%20Niklaus%20Wirth.pdf), which has a chapter on recursion (and when not to use it).